# C# appsetttings bind array of objects to class

Tags: c#, json, binding, appsettings

I have int appsettings.js section like that:

```
 "AccessKeys": {
    "user1": {
      "pass": ""
    },
```

I created classes in C# to bind this section to these classes:

public class AccessKeys
{
public List Users = new List();
}

```
public class AccessKeyUserJson
{
    public AccessKeyUser AccessKeyUser { get; set; }
}

public class AccessKeyUser
{
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

I bind above classes in `Startup.cs`:

```
  services.Configure<AppSettingsConfig>(Configuration);
```

In `AppSettingsConfig` I have property `AccessKeys` and this property is binded correctly but `Users` is empty (0 items)

---

I changed structure:

```
"AccessKeys": [
    {
      "user1": "",
      "pass": ""
    },
]
```

Comment: `AccessKeyUserJson` need a method named `user1`. If you need an array try with `"AccessKey": [ { "user1": ....},  { "user2": ....},  ]` and then use a property array `AccessKeyUser[]`

Comment: Obviously because there is no `Users` in `AccessKeys` ... It looks more like dictionary not list ... so basically your model is different than json content

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myJSONstring)))
{
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer js = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(myStruct));
    myStruct aux = (myStruct)js.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

This is a single level approach, and sincerely, I've never tried to cast anything in a sub-classing scheme but maybe it worths trying.

As you can see, here, the JSON string is taken by a Memory Stream and then casted into the final struct/class.

Comment: it's about [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/) not general json parsing